# Is it possible to use other JavaVersion in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to change this part of my gradle.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Each time I find a post about how to fix the current error a new error appears.

I'm trying to include a java library in an android studio project.
The library uses JDK 14 or higher.
So I downloaded jdk-14.0.2 and updated the variable JAVA_HOME to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-14.0.2`
(after struggling to make android studio compile with this one)
I can compile a new project just changing the JDK to use in Project structure -> JDK location.

But updating the JavaVersion to any higher number throws `error: package android.os does not exist`
Solved it adding this to dependencies
`implementation files("${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar")`

But now I get several of these errors
`com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: Unsupported class file version: 58`
Others are in java.lang or other places, but all say `Unsupported class file version: 58`

Is there a way to make android studio properly work with a higher JavaVersion?
All posts I see say that is as simple as just change the JDK location, but it hasn't been like that.

Comment: Apparently Java 11 source code features are supported in AGP 7.0.  See https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently android can only work up to Java11.
I found this when gradle updated to 7.0, this version required Java11.
Seems for this you also need to have Android Studio Arctic Fox.

With this my app's gradle can have this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```